# Does Indonesia restrict chicken wings import under the pretext of halal certification?

Tags: trade, indonesia

I couldn't find the link on the

1. Americans do not like chicken wings enough. The consumption is far less than production. That's because the chickens are injected with so many hormons on their wings.
2. Chicken wings are cheaper in US and the americans pretty much want to dump their chicken wings everywhere.
3. Indonesians restrict import under the pretext that the chicken wings are not halal because they are not slaughtered properly.
4. Clinton tried to persuade Indonesians' politicians to allow the chicken wings import anyway and agree to open up american market for more indonesian product in return.

Can anyone verify that?

Here is an article on that

http://www.arabnews.com/node/1191166/business-economy

Not exactly against american. More like Indonesia imposes halal ban on all chickens.

Comment: Trade restrictions for purely economic reasons, protecting national industries, are not uncommon.

Comment: The EU has had  a ban on US poultry meat since 1997 because the quality is below EU standards. It doesn't exactly stretch the imagination that it doesn't come up to halal requirements either,  so it might be more of a. "genuine reason"  than a "pretext"

Comment: Incidentally the only Muslim country in the top 10 list of destinations for US chicken exports is Iraq (2016 - most event data I've found at the moment) . Which might well be something they signed to when weren't in a position to say no to when under a government entirely beholden to the US

Comment: Re #1, chicken wings are actually quite popular in the US.  IDK if they're under-consumed relative to other chicken parts, (Anecdotally, it seems as though more chicken wings are consumed than there are chickens to produce them :-))  If so, it has nothing to do with hormone injections in them - something I'd never heard of before reading this post.

Comment: Why would halal certification be a "pretext"? It's a religious requirement for Muslims, so it can be a genuine concern for a Muslim country.

Comment: because the true purpose is to protect the chicken industry from the chicken import. Also most indonesian customers may not care that much about halal certificate. They will eat chicken even without those halal certificate.

Comment: It is not uncommon..  Grape products created by gentiles are in fact not kosher... that's why we have https://www.kosherwine.com/    Religious economic protectionism is tight!!

Comment: @Erwan: Indonesia is not a "Muslim country", it's a multi-religious country that happens to have a very large Muslim population. But there are enough non-Muslims to make the import of non-halal food economically viable.

Comment: @MSalters Indonesia population is 87% Muslim and the largest Muslim-majority country in the world, it's not a big simplification to call it a Muslim country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is protecting local agriculture.

A nation that can't produce enough food to feed its people can find itself in a very precarious position. If that external food supply gets cut off, they're in real trouble. All the logic in the world won't stop hungry people from rebelling against the government. And farms can't just be started up in a few weeks like a factory. It can take years to bring a farm to full productivity.

So it is in a nation's best interests to encourage local agriculture. In the event of conflict - military or economic - they are less vulnerable to a food cutoff. Even just the possibility of a food cutoff can alter how a nation that imports a lot of its food approaches negotiations. Nations do this by keeping agricultural product prices up to where local farms remain economically viable.

This basic fact runs into conflict with free trade agreements and low cost international transport. Putting a tariff on imported food to keep local farms going invites retaliatory tariffs by the other nation, which can harm other industries that depend on exports.

Some nations have become creative in how they try to keep low cost food out without getting hit by tariffs in return... the EU's anti-GMO stance may well have its roots in protecting local agriculture without getting hit with tariffs in return. Ironically, Monsanto, the largest global producer of GMO seeds, is owned by Bayer, a Germany company... which tends to undermine the argument that the EU has genuine health concerns about GMO crops.

Nor is this the first time chickens have been at the center of a trade disagreements. Chickens can be produced at very low cost, and shipped at very low cost. Consider the [Chicken Tax War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_tax) that blew up between the US and France/West Germany in the early 1960's, culminating in Lyndon Johnson instituting retaliatory tariffs that remain in effect today. From this, one can understand why the EU would get creative in instituting future agricultural protections.

So Indonesia may well be keeping chicken wing prices up, so that local farmers can produce them and make a living, without being blatantly obvious about it by claiming that US chicken wings aren't halal.

Comment: However, it would seem that chicken wings (without the rest of the chicken) aren't really something that could be produced by local agriculture, or which are a staple food.  If protection of local agriculture was indeed the reason, one would think that more basic foods such as rice would be protected even more zealously.